# Ошибка: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. 400.Bad Request: chat not found"

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Идея такова: бот подвязан к группе и через бот можно отправлять сообщения в неё. Когда группа была обычной, всё отлично работало. После того как она стала супер группой, я поменял *id* на текущее *id* группы и все нужные права бота, но все равно выдаёт:
`A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found.`
Кто знает как решить эту проблему?)

Comment: Ид чата проверьте, и разрешения бота в этом чате. И было бы неплохо код прикрепить к вопросу, где видно как вы передаёте ид чата

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка указывает на то, что вы не верно указали токен или не верным путем, попробуйте так:

```
import telebot
token='ваш токен' # не забудьте перенести его потом в .env
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)  
# далее расписываете функционал
```

Ошибка 400 - означает, что такого чата не существует.
запускаете бота, переходите в желаемую группу, добавляете бота и даете ему права АДМИНИСТРАТОРА;
Если вы привязывали бота через сам код, то в случае с супергруппой такой подход не корректный, нужно именно в ручную через сам телеграмм его добавлять;
Если и это не помогает, тогда проверьте корректность вашего токена;

Comment: 'chat not found' - переводится как "чат не найден", из этого следует вывод, что неверно передается ид чата

Comment: у меня была такая-же ошибка один раз, когда не правильно был указан API, но в любом случае тут проблема скорее в том, что бот был не правильно добавлен в супергруппу.